# How to delay jQuery function before next execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a relatively simple jQuery function that has a conditional and some class additions and slide toggles.

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
    if($('#header .nav').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#header .nav').removeClass('open');
        $('#header .nav').slideToggle();
        $('#header .nav').delay(400).removeAttr('style'); <---DELAY THIS LINE
    } else {
        $('#header .nav').addClass('open');
        $('#header .nav').slideToggle();
    }
    $('div').toggleClass('isActive');
});
```

On the fifth line of code, I'm trying to delay the removal of the style attribute. I'm basically trying to get it to finish the slide toggle above before it removes the attribute.  I've tried using `.delay` as you can see, but it doesn't work. It still executes the removal at the same time as the slide.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that because [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr) does not work with the queue, methods like `animation()`/`slideDown()` works with the delay queue that is why we can chain their execution with [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) call.

You can use a simple setTimeout() to do this.

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#header .nav').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#header .nav').removeClass('open');
        $('#header .nav').slideToggle();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#header .nav').removeAttr('style');
        }, 400)
    } else {
        $('#header .nav').addClass('open');
        $('#header .nav').slideToggle();
    }
    $('div').toggleClass('isActive');
});
```

---

You can use delay by add a callback to the queue like

```
$('#header .nav').delay(400).queue(function (nxt) {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
    nxt();
})
```

---

But you can simplify your code to

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    var $nav = $('#header .nav');
    $nav.toggleClass('open').slideToggle(function () {
        if (!$nav.hasClass('open')) {
            $nav.removeAttr('style');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you! All of these answers work as I need, but you explained why, and I appreciate that!

Comment: @Thomas Nolan check my answer

Comment: I will when I can, it won't let me yet, that's why I have not.

Comment: @ThomasNolan you can also use delay as updated above by using a queue callback

Comment: @ArunPJohny As far i know, `delay` can be used with effects queue, So I think this will not work as we expected `$('#header .nav').delay(400).removeAttr('style');` I just tested it out here. http://jsfiddle.net/msLkao1j/ Please correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy see how it can be used http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c5r7ap71/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ok. I just confused by seeing your typo. See the first code snippet in your post. It contains the following line. `$('#header .nav').delay(400).removeAttr('style');` It needs to be edited. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think for your purpose you can use the slideToggle as given below why you need to write **delay()** or **setInterwal** while **slideToggle()** provides this facility please try this

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
    if($('#header .nav').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#header .nav').removeClass('open');
        $('#header .nav').slideToggle(function(){
             $(this).removeAttr('style'); <---DELAY THIS LINE ///(Will execute after the toggle will executed);
        });
       
    } else {
        $('#header .nav').addClass('open');
        $('#header .nav').slideToggle();
    }
    $('div').toggleClass('isActive');
});
```

here i attach the sample example for the above liked code...!!

[Sample Demo running example](https://jsfiddle.net/k81g05nd/)

Comment: @Thomas Nolan hi i have created a simple example as like what you want please look at out

Answer (score 0):

The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases. (source: https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Use this:

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
      $('#header .nav').removeAttr('style');
  }, 400);
```